# how to apply pagination Using mysql using page number

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Device_Filter_Scan_SP`(in offsetvalue int,
in device_id int,
in search_term varchar(60),
in device_name varchar(60),

in device_Number varchar(60),
in device_os varchar(60),
in device_workingstatus int,
in device_status int,

out total int)
BEGIN


declare device_id_U int (10) default null;
declare device_workingstatus_U int (10) default null;
declare device_status_U int (10) default null;

if( device_id =5) then
set device_id_U=null;
end if;

if( device_workingstatus =5) then
set device_workingstatus_U=null;
end if;

if( device_status =5) then
set device_status_U=null;
end if;


if (offsetvalue<10) then
select distinct(deviceId),deviceName,deviceNumber,deviceWorkingStatus,
os, resolution,displayDensity,serialNo,remarks,status
 from Device_Filter_Scan_View  where  deviceId like 

  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_id_U,''),'%') and  searchTerm like
   CONCAT('%',COALESCE(search_term,''),'%') and  

   deviceName like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_name,''),'%') and

 deviceNumber    like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_Number,''),'%') and
  os like 
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_os,''),'%') and
  deviceWorkingStatus like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_workingstatus_U,''),'%') and
  status like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_status_U,''),'%') limit 10 offset 10
 ;

 else
 select  distinct(deviceId),deviceName,deviceNumber,deviceWorkingStatus,
os, resolution,displayDensity,serialNo,remarks,status
 from Device_Filter_Scan_View where  deviceId like 

  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_id_U,''),'%') and  searchTerm like
   CONCAT('%',COALESCE(search_term,''),'%') and  
   deviceName like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_name,''),'%') and
   deviceNumber    like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_Number,''),'%') and
  os like 
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_os,''),'%') and
  deviceWorkingStatus like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_workingstatus_U,''),'%') and
  status like
  CONCAT('%',COALESCE(device_status_U,''),'%')  
 limit 10 offset offsetvalue
 ;
 end if;

END
```

this is procudure i have to apply pagination where offset is page number so if offset is less than 10 then it should display first 10 item and if offsetvalue greater than 10 then it should display next 10 till that offset value if after searching record is more than 10 then only we have to apply pagination please suggest  me in this am facing problem to solve this issue

Comment: Didn't understand clearly. Dont u have any page size (number of records per page) parameter? In pagination two parameters are usually required 1) page size (LIMT) and current page number (offset).

Comment: @1000111 u for got Chat Link can you please give me